# iOS - NotificationCenter addObserver "UIMenuControllerWillHideMenu"

Tags: ios, swift, observers, uimenucontroller, notificationcenter

I have added notification observer for `UIMenuControllerWillHideMenu` but it does not call selector added/associated with notification center.

`UIMenuControllerWillHideMenu` is notification center identifier for `UIMenuController` and should be called when `UIMenuController` will hide. But somehow it's not working.

Here is code I've tried (Swift 3.x):

```
private func addMenuObserverNotification(){
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(self.menuControllerWillHideMenu), name: NSNotification.Name(rawValue: "UIMenuControllerWillHideMenu"), object: nil)
}

// This function should be called on 'UIMenuControllerWillHideMenu'
func menuControllerWillHideMenu() -> Void {
    removeMenuObserverNotification()
}


private func removeMenuObserverNotification(){
    NotificationCenter.default.removeObserver(self)
}
```

Unable to identify, what's wrong.

Comment: FYI - Replace `NSNotification.Name(rawValue: "UIMenuControllerWillHideMenu")` with just `.UIMenuControllerWillHideMenu`.

Comment: I found the mistake. thanks @rmaddy  & wm.p1us

Comment: Post a proper answer describing what you did to fix the issue if you think it will help others. Otherwise, delete your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a solution by replacing `NSNotification.Name(rawValue: "UIMenuControllerWillHideMenu")` with just `.UIMenuControllerWillHideMenu`

```
private func addMenuObserverNotification(){
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(self.menuControllerWillHideMenu), name: .UIMenuControllerWillHideMenu), object: nil)
}
```

I did a mistake by adding it's initializer `NSNotification.Name(rawValue: "UIMenuControllerWillHideMenu")`, which may not require as [NSNotificationName](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsnotificationname?language=objc) is `typedef NSString`, which directly allows an access to predefined values using `.<value name>`

For more details: 

[addObserver:selector:name:object:](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsnotificationcenter/1415360-addobserver?language=objc)

[NSNotificationName](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsnotificationname?language=objc)